# get all documents from the elasticsearch 5.6

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am using elasticsearch 5.6 java API.

When I am trying to get all the documents from the elasticsearch it's not fetching all records because there is a limit in ES which is of 9999.

To get the all the documents I can use Scroll API or other methods which are used only for pagination.

I want to get all the records and store it an arraylist.

error :

> Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhaseExecutionException: Batch size is too large, size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [100000]. Scroll batch sizes cost as much memory as result windows so they are controlled by the [index.max_result_window] index level setting.

I have also increase index.max_results_window to 500000 as below but I didn't worked

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/index/_settings -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ "max_result_window" : 500000 }"

Comment: You need to use Scroll API, otherwise your nodes can have performance issues and even go down if you want all documents at once.

Comment: To get the all the documents I can use Scroll API or other methods which are used only for pagination.                                                                            I want to get all the records and store it an arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

For Kiru or whomever else comes across this, putting "index.max_result_window" in my elasticsearch.yml file worked to increase the limit.